# Simple banner Ad - Is there a better way to layout for desktop and mobile? ( Flexbox / CSS Grid)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to create a simple html banner ad and make it responsive for desktop and mobile. 
My current version works for desktop but I am pretty sure that using a lot of absolute position is not the best to approach this.
I have been looking at Flexbox or CSS Grid and thought that might be a route to go. I have also thought about using simple Bootstrap columns. Any advice on the most efficient way to accomplish this?

I feel like i have a good bit of CSS set that I dont really need. Looking to make this as simple as possible.

[image: Mockup of Banner Ad]

```
<div class='ad-banner-container'>
  <div class='full-size-banner'>
  <div class='image-container'>
    <img class='banner-image' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Img Alt Text">
  </div>
  <div class='text-column'>
    <p class='ad-title'>Ad Title</p>
    <p class='ad-body-text'>This is where the detail text goes</p>
  </div>
  <button class='cta-btn' data-target="#myModal">Call to Action</button>
</div>
```

[Link to Codepen with current version - HTML and CSS](https://codepen.io/powellmap/pen/yLyeNrE)

Answer (score 1):

I used Sass and custom tags, sorry. But I had fun with this.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bstees/pen/KKwVVqw

HTML

```
<banner-container>
  <banner-ad>
    <image-container>
      <img class='banner-image' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Img Alt Text">
    </image-container>
    <text-column>
      <p class='ad-title'>Ad Title</p>
      <p class='ad-body-text'>This is where the detail text goes</p>
    </text-column>
    <button data-target="#myModal">Call to Action</button>
  </banner-ad>

</banner-container>
```

SASS

```
banner-container {
  height: 160px;
  padding: 36px;
  background-color: #F2F7F7;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  * { box-sizing: border-box; }

}

banner-ad {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 1082px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  image-container {
    flex: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-right: 36px;
    img {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
    }
  }

  text-column {
    display: block;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 1em;
    min-width: 600px;

    .ad-title {
      font-size: 18px;
      color: black;
      margin: 5px 5px 15px 5px;
    }

    .ad-body-text {
      margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  }

  button {
    border: 2px solid #007DBA;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #007DBA;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    flex: 1 0;
  }

  button:hover {
    background-color: #007DBA;
    border-color: #007DBA;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```